# Regex for ignoring matches

Tags: regex

```
*test*
**test**
***test***
```

In the above case, I want to match only `*test*` ignoring all other cases in a multiline text. Can anyone give me guidance on how to do this using regular expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
(?<!\*)\*test\*(?!\*)
```

It uses negative look around to check whether there is an `*` before of after the match.

You can check that it does what you want: https://regex101.com/r/G23yZL/1

`(?!x)` is a negative look ahead. It checks that what is *after* the match is not a `x`.

`(?<!x)` is a negative look behind. It checks that what is *before* the match is not `x`.

Note that there also exist positive look ahead `(?=x)` (resp. look behind `(?<=x)`). It will check if what is after (resp. behind) the match *is* a `x`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation too. It helped me a lot in understanding the look around part of the regex. This solution worked for me. Thanks again for the help.